# PHP Calendar is broken after leap year

Tags: php, calendar

I am trying to fix a problem with a php calendar that tracks a particular work schedule. I just checked how its going to look into 2021 and its off right from the beginning of the year.

I am thinking this could be because of the leap year in 2020. But I am not sure. I am trying to troubleshoot and fix someone else's work (who I cant get in touch with). My knowledge of PHP is minimal unfortunately.

The array that defines the work schedule 'pattern' is set out like so:

```
function buildWorkDayArray($platoon) {
    $arr[0] = array(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE); // 4th week
    $arr[1] = array(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE); // 1st week
    $arr[2] = array(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE); // 2nd week
    $arr[3] = array(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE); // 3rd week
    for($i = 1; $i < $platoon; $i++) { array_unshift($arr, array_pop($arr)); }
    return $arr;
```

And as I mentioned earlier the first week of 2021 the pattern is duplicated, and then continues as it should, but that causes the schedule to be off for the rest of the year.

January looks like this, the grey circles are scheduled shifts.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnrLs.jpg

The first week of the year 53, 0, 1 whatever it wants to be called is correct in being Friday and Sunday. But the next week should be Wednesday, Saturday.

Here is the entire function that builds the calendar.

```
function buildYearlyCalendars($platoon, $year) {
    $template = buildYearlyArray($year);
    if($platoon == NULL) {
      return 'No platoon has been defined...';
    } else {
      $html = NULL;
      $m = 1;
      $requests = currentRequests($platoon, $year, $template); // Retrieve info on requests already placed for that year
      $workDayStatus = $requests[1];
      //echo '<PRE>',print_r($workDayStatus),'</PRE>';
      $requests = $requests[0];
      $requests = addToasts($platoon, $year, $requests); // Add in the toast info for those days
      $workDays = buildWorkDayArray($platoon); // Build our 28-day array
      //$workDayStatus = getDateCounts($platoon, $year); // Retrieve counts on requests already placed for that year
      foreach($template as $month) {
        $html .= '    <TABLE cellspacing="0" class="myDesign2">
        <THEAD>
          <TR><TH colspan="8">' . date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 15)) . '</TH></TR>
        </THEAD>
        <TBODY>
          <TR><TD>#</TD><TD>MON</TD><TD>TUE</TD><TD>WED</TD><TD>THU</TD><TD>FRI</TD><TD>SAT</TD><TD>SUN</TD></TR>' . "\n";
        $offset = date('N', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1, $year)); // Defines the numeric "Day of the Week" the first day lands
        for($i = 1, $padding = NULL; $i < $offset; $i++) { $padding .= '<TD></TD>'; } // Prepares the empty days prior to the 1st of the month
        $col = $row = 1;
        $length = count($month);
        foreach($month as $dkey => $day) { // $dkey is the array's index, while $day is the value it holds
          $key = array_search($year . '-' . sprintf("%02d", $m) . '-' . sprintf("%02d", $dkey), array_column($workDayStatus, 0)); // Fetches key to reference IF day has request offs
          //$class = strlen($key) != 0 ? $workDayStatus[$key][3] : 'working'; // Fetches the class for circle color of that day
          $am = isset($workDayStatus[$m][$dkey]['am'])? $workDayStatus[$m][$dkey]['am'] : 0;
          $pm = isset($workDayStatus[$m][$dkey]['pm'])? $workDayStatus[$m][$dkey]['pm'] : 0;
          $rank = isset($workDayStatus[$m][$dkey]['rank'])? $workDayStatus[$m][$dkey]['rank'] : 0;
          $class = circleColor($am + $pm, $rank); // Fetches the class for circle color of that day
          $week = ltrim(date('W', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $dkey, $year)), '0'); // Defines week of year
          $weekIndex = $week % 4; // Defines remainder of week 0-3
          if($col%7 == 1) { $html .= '        <TR style="height: 50px"><TD>' . $week . '</TD>'; } // Prints week # only at beginning of week
          if($dkey == 1) { $html .= $padding; $col = $col + $offset - 1; }; // Adds in prepared blank columns before the 1st of a month
          // Defines SPAN to style related days, otherwise defaults. The 'title' attribute defines the text during "onMouseOver". &#013;&#010; is \r\n, which is the return/newline for Windows/*nix systems
          //$day = $workDays[$weekIndex][($col - 1) % 7] == TRUE ? '<SPAN class="circles ' . $class . '">' . $dkey . '<SPAN class="hideMe"><SPAN class="requests">' . $requests[$m][$dkey][10] . '</SPAN></SPAN></SPAN>' : $dkey;
          $day = $workDays[$weekIndex][($col - 1) % 7] == TRUE ? 
          '<SPAN class="circles ' . $class[0] . ' ' . $class[1] . '" onclick="M.toast({html: \'Date: ' .  date('F ', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 10))  .$dkey . " " . $year . $requests[$m][$dkey][10]
          /* display whats available */ .
           '\', displayLength:      \'100000\'})">' . $dkey . '</SPAN>' : $dkey;
          $html .= '<TD>' . $day . '</TD>'; // Defines the week's daily cells, and if working or not
          if($col%7 == 0) { $html .= '</TR>' . "\n"; $row++; } // Closes a row at week end
          $col++; // Increases our referenced column # by 1
        }
        while(($dkey + $offset) <= $row * 7 && ($col - 1) % 7 != 0) { $html .= '<TD></TD>'; $dkey++; } // Adds in blank days to finish off final week of month
        if($row == 5 || ($col-1)%7 == 0) { $html .= '        <TR style="height: 50px"><TD colspan="8"></TD>';} // Adds in blank week to make a 5-week structure into a 6-week
        $html .= '</TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>' . "\n";
        $m++;
      }
      return $html;
    }
  }
```

I cant figure out how to correct it. If someone could point me in the right direction for what to attempt I would really appreciate it. I am happy to research and learn. I am just not sure where to start.

Thanks so much for any input.

Comment: Can you please explain the business logic? How should the calendar work, how do you calculate the scheduled days?

Comment: Yes, please explain the rules of the pattern.